# Pin tab by default?

Tags: firefox, vimperator, browser-tabs, pentadactyl

Is there a way to make firefox open tab as a pin tab by default?

I often work with multiple tabs. My "home page" alone is 7 tabs already. I pin them all, still it'll be better for me to open all tabs as pin tabs.

**Possible solution**

A possible solution to open a url as a pin tab with, say, Ctrl-Click or open a selected url with from a keyboard.

As to a second approach -- there's a function `:pintab` in [pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/index). One can pin a tab from keyboard with:

```
map x :pintab<CR>
```

When the focus is on the url -- `Ctrl-Shift-Return` opens the url in a new tab. I tried to combine the two things:

```
map x <C-S-CR>:pintab<CR>
```

but it doesn't work. Probably `<C-S-CR>` is illigal.

(actually a proper way to pin tab [is](http://pentablg.blogspot.ru/2011/05/apology.html) `map -g user <C-S-p> -ex pintab!` -- this way one gets toggler)

Comment: Are you looking to make the tab width smaller (same size as pinned tabs)??

Answer (score 3):

## `set apptab=true`

It works for Vimperator 3.8.2. (May '14)

Comment: does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which works with pentadactyl (probably will work in Vimperator too):

```
" auto-pin tab:
autocmd PageLoad * js if(!getBrowser().mCurrentTab.pinned) getBrowser().pinTab(getBrowser().mCurrentTab);
```

(originally from [here](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/11/auto-pinning-tabs-in-firefox-using.html), modified to match all URLs).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `:tab pintab <URL>`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, it works on opened buffers only. Sorry

Comment: Look at the [official tab lugin](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/plugins#tab-options-plugin). It seems to be possible to use it and integrate the pintab support into it

Comment: The tab plugin doesn't seem to be concerned with pintabs. Nor description, nor it's source have a single pintab word.

Comment: I didn't tell you that. It is a plugin to manage tabs placement. You may add yourself the needed code to it and call the needed function via keybindings (look at :to in the end of the documentation, e.g the end of the file)